# steps to install cryptogen tool for hyperledger fabric node setup?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am a java developer and i have started learning hyperledger fabric . I am trying to do the setup for fabric node setup . I am not sure how to install cryptogen tool .

Please help me .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For Linux users:**
The installation process of binaries tools for Hyperledger Fabric is captured in the [download platform-specific binaries](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html) section.

You need to run:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh | bash
```

It will download required files. Make sure you have all [prerequisite](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/prereqs.html) installed and configured as well.

**For MacOSX users**: 
you can also use Homebrew to install the Hyperledger Fabric binaries:

```
brew tap hyperledger/fabric
brew install fabric-tools
```

In case you are working with **source code** base you can simply compile it with

```
make cryptogen
```

it will be available at `./build/bin/cryptogen` folder

Comment: $ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh | bash
bash: line 1: 404:: command not found

Comment: fixed the links

Comment: and also add the path.         export PATH=<path to download location>/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround and works only when you have Fabric installed into you Go workspace, but works like a charm.

Go to your Bash profile and add following line:

`export PATH="$HOME/Go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/bin:$PATH"`

In other words, you are linking the Fabric crypto tools that are located in the `.build/bin/` that they are:

- `chaintool`
- `configtxgen`
- `cryptogen`

after that you will be able to use these tools directly. But remember that they will won't work anymore if you will move o remove the hyperledger/fabric folder into you Go workspace.