# Cannot find cryptogen tool in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to generate end2end crypto-config artifacts. I need to execute following command :

```
build/bin/cryptogen generate --config crypto-config.yaml --output=crypto-config
```

Kindly let me know where i can find cryptogen tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [steps to install cryptogen tool for hyperledger fabric node setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498921/steps-to-install-cryptogen-tool-for-hyperledger-fabric-node-setup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Fabric [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) page you will see a link to [Download Platform-specific binaries](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) including cryptogen.

If you have cloned the source code, then from the /fabric directory you can

```
make cryptogen
```

and find it at /fabric/build/bin/cryptogen.

Comment: ./bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
org2.example.com

sleep $SLEEP_TIMEOUT

KEYSTORE=`ls ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/$ORG_DOMAIN/users/Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN/msp/keystore`
ls ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/$ORG_DOMAIN/users/Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN/msp/keystore
composer identity import \
-p hlfv1 \
-u Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN \
-c ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/$ORG_DOMAIN/users/Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN/msp/signcerts/Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN-cert.pem \
-k ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/$ORG_DOMAIN/users/Admin@$ORG_DOMAIN/msp/keystore/$KEYSTORE

Comment: module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './api'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Comment: I am very new to this so please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot comment because I haven't posted enough here, but as user324781's answer no longer works:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-1.1/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash
```

The issue was just that the link is out of date, so if this crops up again, just go on their repo and find scripts/bootstrap.sh file.

[Update]

The above may or may not have contributed to the solution, but either way it didn't seem to do anything on my machine.

First I made sure that my fabric-samples folder was up to date, I'm unsure if this helped but here if anyone is trying to copy. I followed the steps [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html):

```
cd ~/Build-Multi-Host-Network-Hyperledger/
git clone -b master https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
cd fabric-samples
git checkout master
```

then running (replacing ubuntu with your username):

```
cd ~/Build-Multi-Host-Network-Hyperledger/
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/Build-Multi-Host-Network-Hyperledger/bin:$PATH
```

Based on this, and how the problem was solved, probably run the updated version of user's script, and add that dir to the path.

Hopefully, this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps to install cryptogen as is in same sequence -

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/
cd fabric
make cryptogen
make docker
PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux users:** 
   The installation process of binaries tools for Hyperledger Fabric is captured in the download platform-specific binaries section.

You need to run:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-1.1/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash
```

It will download required files. Make sure you have all prerequisite installed and configured as well.

**For MacOSX users:** 
   You can also use Homebrew to install the Hyperledger Fabric binaries:

```
brew tap hyperledger/fabric
brew install fabric-tools
```

Comment: $ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh | bash
bash: line 1: 404:: command not found

Comment: Quote from a low rep user (Ben Hayward): *"Sorry, I cannot comment because I haven't posted enough here, but as user324781's answer no longer works. The issue was just that the link is out of date, so if this crops up again, just go on their repo and find scripts/bootstrap.sh file."*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps

`export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:${PWD}:$PATH
 export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}
 export VERBOSE=false`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but after adding `cyptogen` tool folder to path variable this issue resolved.

`export PATH=$PATH:/workspace/relianceSupplyChain/bin`